# How to disable open a new tab on form submit?

Tags: window.open, window.opener

i have this search form and when you hit search it takes you to new window!
i make a search on the code for (window) and i got this!
any solutions?

```
    // and open it in a new tab
        window.open(url,'_newtab');
    });
},
```

i want it to open the same tab

Answer (score 0):

I think is browser dependent, some of them open windows on tabs when you set target='_blank'